# Real time tracking WebAPi for Google Map with Ap.net WebAPI

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a project where I have to create the Web APi for Android on Real time tracking of app.
How can I implement the real time tracking and if one device send (Post()) the data say  latitude and longitude.  So where I store that lat and long So if and another device ask (Get()) for that data I can return that.

Comment: Do you have a database set up?

Comment: Database is not goo soloution

Comment: How long does the data need to be valid for? You could use in-memory storage. But ASP.NET could recycle the app and you can lose the data at any time. You need to store the data outside the app for it to be reliable.